# ZSH Shell history not working

Tags: zsh

I recently switched from bash to zshell but my history does not seem to be working. when I press the up arrow I don't get the previous commands. Is the shortcut different? Also how do I enable shared history through tabs and new windows? I am on Lion, and using the standard Terminal

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/470335/zsh-shell-history-not-working/470356#470356) answer.

Answer (score 96):

Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
SAVEHIST=1000  # Save most-recent 1000 lines
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: couldn't figure out why `setopt inc_append_history share_history` wasn't working. This fixed it.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me as well. Can you put this as an answer?

Comment: What does `SAVEHIST=10` do?

Comment: eivindml, it controls max number of records in history, I believe.

Comment: @DimiDak, sure. Of course, value can be increased. Check http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html for more info (particularly 2.5.4).

Answer (score 29):

To add to user RoboSloNE, if you've double checked that you have set SAVEHIST and HISTFILE via:

```
$echo $HISTFILE
 ~/.zsh_history
$echo $SAVEHIST
 100
```

Then the next step is to check the permissions of the HISTFILE:

```
$ls -l $HISTFILE
 -rw-------  1 user  staff  3722 Aug  8 11:29 /Users/user/.zsh_history
```

Your user need to have read/write access on this file to use it as your history file. I've noticed that installing oh-my-zsh as root will set this file permission to root, so you'll need to:

```
$chown user:group $HISTFILE
```

Comment: When I run `echo $SAVEHIST`, I get `zsh: command not found: 10000`. Nothing gets written to my `$HISTFILE`. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the group here?

Answer (score 8):

I have resolved zsh history using setup below
vim ~/.zshrc

```
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
```

But I have issue with reading from history. I need to cleanup file manually `~/.histfile` and then start to work.

Hope this help you a bit.

Answer (score -2):

If all of these didn't work, my suggestion is to check the authority of the file `~/.zsh_history`.

For example, enter

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: that's a _horrible_ idea. why would you want the world to be able to read your history, which includes typos and other stuff. Moreover, `chmod 777` means it's executable anyone can write to it. That means another user can write to a file in your home directory and you could accidentally run it and it could be destructive.